# Sort element based on date and time

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting

I have a list of elements with attributes containing the date and time the element was created.

```
<ul>
   <li data-clock="6/9/2017, 6:53:56 PM"></li>
   <li data-clock="5/8/2017, 5:33:56 PM"></li>
   <li data-clock="6/7/2017, 4:13:56 PM"></li>
</ul>
```

How can I sort the elements starting with the oldest when a `<button>` is clicked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to select all the `li` elements, sort them using `.sort()` function with a custom function that uses `getAttribute('data-clock')` to get the values and `(new Date(b.getAttribute('data-clock'))).getTime()` to compare the dates:

```
$ul.find('li.unsorted').sort(function(a, b) {
   return (new Date(a.getAttribute('data-clock'))).getTime() > (new Date(b.getAttribute('data-clock')).getTime()) ? -1 : 1;
})
```

**Demo:**

```js
var $ul = $('ul');
$("#sorter").click(function() {
  $ul.find('li.unsorted').sort(function(a, b) {
      return (new Date(a.getAttribute('data-clock'))).getTime() > (new Date(b.getAttribute('data-clock')).getTime()) ? -1 : 1;
    })
    .appendTo($ul);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="sorter">Sort</button>
<ul>
  <li class="unsorted" data-clock="6/9/2017, 6:53:56 PM">6/9/2017, 6:53:56 PM</li>
  <li class="unsorted" data-clock="5/8/2017, 5:33:56 PM">5/8/2017, 5:33:56 PM</li>
  <li class="unsorted" data-clock="6/7/2017, 4:13:56 PM">6/7/2017, 4:13:56 PM</li>
</ul>
```